# Cannot get list of albums Facebook GraphRequest Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am try to get facebook shared albums from facebook GraphRequest API. in loadAlbum method can get only id as a object , this is facebook sdk `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'`  i tried to get using facebook grapAPI here it gives all results but not give in my android application response object only give `{"id":"5507801********"}` this.

[image]
here my onCreate method

```
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setupfb();
        loggedIn = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null;

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile,user_photos"));

            }
        });

        if (loggedIn) {
            loadAlbums();
        }
```

and here my loadAlbums() method

```
public void loadAlbums() {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        try {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "response" + object, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d("albums", object.toString());
                            if (response.getConnection().getResponseCode() == 200) {

                                ArrayList<String> photos = new ArrayList<String>();
                                ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
                                Log.d("albums", object.toString());

                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "albums.limit(400){picture{url},name}");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }
```

and setFb method()

```
  private void setupfb() {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            loadAlbums();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Canceld", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and here my onActivityResults method

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is a administrator issue, need to give a permission for developer logging account in corresponding facebook appId..